# Is Debian package ifenslave really necessary for bonding?

Tags: debian, debian-wheezy, bonding, dpkg

[This](https://wiki.debian.org/Bonding) piece of Debian documentation states that package `ifenslave` is necessary for bonding:

> First install the ifenslave package, necessary to enable bonding

Yet I know of two Debian 7.10 (wheezy) hosts where `dpkg --get-selections | grep ifenslave` returns `ifenslave-2.6 install` (i.e. package is not installed) *and* there are multiple entries `/proc/net/bonding/*` with `MII Status: up`.

So is package `ifenslave` really necessary for bonding or is it not?

Comment: Interestingly, I tried this on one of my SLES 11 SP3 servers. running `rpm -qa` doesn't show `ifenslave`, although it definitely is installed, but via the package `iputils-ss021109-292.28.1`. Maybe it behaves like this in Debian. Also: you can bond interfaces without the use of `ifenslave`, it's just much trickier.

Comment: https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/ifenslave-2.6

Comment: https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/ifenslave

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the `ifenslave` package is not required on Debian systems. From that package's README.Debian (Debian 9 system):

> [The] best way to configure bonding is via the files in `/sys/class/net/$master/bonding/`. This Debian package therefore does not contain the binary from the kernel sources, but provides a shell script with identical functionality.
>   ...
>
> You can also enslave interfaces using Debian's /etc/network/interfaces file:
>
> ...

Using the `/etc/networking/interfaces` approach results in bonding being configured by setting values in `/sys`. The `ifenslave` approach merely provides a shell script to make configuration easier.